# Find the maximum value(s) from a column and selecting their rows

Tags: mysql, sql, max

After looking at other examples I still have not been able to find a solution, that is why I am asking for some help.

My table structure:

```
 V_id | name | group_id | other columns
 ----------------------
   1  |      |    1     
   2  |      |    1     
   3  |      |    2     
   4  |      |    3     
   5  |      |    3
```

I have been struggling to build a query, to select all the rows which have the maximum value from the group_id column.

therefore output should be like this:

```
V_id | name | group_id | other columns
----------------------
  4  |      |    3     
  5  |      |    3
```

which I believe can be solved by selecting all records where group_id is the highest.

---

and also need a query to get all the other remaining rows.
which in this case, should be like this:

```
V_id | name | group_id | other columns
----------------------
  1  |      |    1     
  2  |      |    1     
  3  |      |    2
```

which I believe can be done by selecting all records where group_id < Max(group_id)

Comment: Show your struggles here please. (the queries you have wrote so far)

Comment: I could not get the syntax correct for the WHERE group_id = (SELECT MAX(group_ID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the first part of the problem,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   group_id = (SELECT MAX(group_ID) FROM TableName)
```

and for the second part,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   group_id < (SELECT MAX(group_ID) FROM TableName)
```

Comment: Thank you jw! I knew it was simple but I could not get the syntax correct.

Comment: what is the query you are executing? what is the error message?

Comment: Your answer was perfect!! I meant I couldnt figure the syntax before you told me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JOIN` for that:

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM Table1 a
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(Group_ID) AS MAXID 
          FROM Table1) B
    ON a.Group_id = B.MaxID;
```

Result:

```
| V_ID |   NAME | GROUP_ID |
----------------------------
|    4 | (null) |        3 |
|    5 | (null) |        3 |
```

For the remaining rows use `LEFT JOIN` with a condition like this:

```
   SELECT a.* 
     FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(Group_ID) AS MAXID 
             FROM Table1) B
       ON a.Group_id = B.MaxID
    WHERE B.MaxID IS NULL;
```

Result:

```
| V_ID |   NAME | GROUP_ID |
----------------------------
|    1 | (null) |        1 |
|    2 | (null) |        1 |
|    3 | (null) |        2 |
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/411fc4/7)

Comment: Thanks for the alternative method.